Is the relationship between a field and principle ideal domain polynomial ring "if" or "iff"?
I have read multiple answers here and some articles on wikipedia. Some say that if $\mathbb{K}[x]$ is a P.I.D. then $\mathbb{K}$ is a field. Others say $\mathbb{K}[x]$ is a P.I.D. if and only if $\mathbb{K}$ is a field. However, others say this only happens if $\mathbb{K}$ is at minimum a "domain". I have also read that $\mathbb{K}$ has to be an integral domain first.
Is this a one-way or two-way result and what is the necessary condition?

I am not sure how this answers my question !!!. This is just lazy of you. That question asks about principal ideal rings.
